# mongoDB array sorting without linq

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am C# mongoDB driver. Below is sample data structure. 
I would like to know what is best way to get the sorted scores without using LINQ or generics.

```
db.students
{ name: 'Jane',
  scores: [
              { course: 'math', marks: '35'},
              { course: 'biology', marks: '50'},
              { course: 'english', marks: '40'}
          ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the aggregate framework of mongoDB and use the $sort and return the document.http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/

Comment: Can you give the sample code on how to use it in C#?